# ReactiveSecurityContextHolder does not return Authenticated User

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, reactive

I am trying to configure a Spring Security within a reactive Spring Boot application and included the parent project that relies on the new Spring-Security version *5.0.0.RC1*:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
</parent>
```

I configured my Spring WebSecurity to use a custom AuthenticationFilter to retrieve my Authentication information as well as a custom AuthenticationManager with my own Providers.

Config:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new CustomServerAuthenticationEntryPoint();

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            // we rely on method security
            .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager())
                //Override BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint
                .exceptionHandling().serverAuthenticationEntryPoint(this.entryPoint)
            .and()
                .addFilterAt(upmAuthenticationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .build();
    }


    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager()
            .authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    private AuthenticationWebFilter upmAuthenticationWebFilter() {
        try {
            AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager());
            authenticationFilter.setServerAuthenticationFailureHandler(new ServerAuthenticationEntryPointFailureHandler(this.entryPoint));
            authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(new CustomAuthenticationConverter(););

            return authenticationFilter;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Could not initialize AuthenticationWebFilter.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

ReactiveAuthenticationManager:

```
public class CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    private List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProvider = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationProvider(
        final AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider.add(customAuthenticationProvider);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(final Authentication authentication) {
        Class<? extends Authentication> toTest = authentication.getClass();
        for(AuthenticationProvider provider: authenticationProvider) {
            if (provider.supports(toTest)) {
                try {

                    //The provider returns a full authenticated Authentication object.
                    //With authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                    return Mono.just(provider.authenticate(authentication));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Credentials"));
                }
            }
        }
        return Mono.error(new ProviderNotFoundException("Unsupported Credentials"));
    }
}
```

When I now perform a call on an Endpoint that requires an authenticated user. As:

```
public interface HelloService {
    /**
     * This method returns just 'Hello, world!'.
     *
     * @return Return 'Hello, world!'.
     */
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    Mono<String> getHelloWorld();
}
```

I always get an 401 AccessDenied Exception.

After Debugging into it at the PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor line 75

```
 auth -> this.preInvocationAdvice.before(auth, invocation, preAttr)
```

I saw that the passed Authentication object is an anonymous user.

Now my question:
Did I forget to configure something for the usage with the ReactiveSecurityContext?

Last week I still used the previous MilestoneRelease M5, where the reactive Spring-Security package was still located extra, under Spring-Security-Reactive. In this case, the authentication object was retrieved and my request could be completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is interested in the problem.

I did not set a *serverSecurityContextRepository* in the AuthenticationWebFilter.

So setting this solved the Problem.

```
private AuthenticationWebFilter upmAuthenticationWebFilter() {
    try {
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager());
        authenticationFilter.setServerAuthenticationFailureHandler(new ServerAuthenticationEntryPointFailureHandler(this.entryPoint));
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(new CustomAuthenticationConverter(););

        //Setting the Context Repo helped
        authenticationFilter.setServerSecurityContextRepository(new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository());

        return authenticationFilter;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BeanInitializationException("Could not initialize AuthenticationWebFilter.", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As setting the repository did not work for me, I just added the Principal to my REST Function:

```
@GetMapping("/select")
public Mono<String> select(java.security.Principal principal) {
     log.debug("Authorities: {}", ((Authentication) principal).getAuthorities());
}
```